# Maximal quotient ring of a commutative ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let  $R$  be  an  associative  ring  in  which  an  identity
element  is  not assumed.  A  right  quotient  ring  of  $R$  is
an  overring  $S$  such  that  for each  $a\in S$  there
corresponds $r\in R$  such  that  $ar\in R$  and  $ar\neq 0$

Is a **MAXIMAL QUOTIENT RING** for $R$ a ring $S$ maximal with
respect to above property?

For a commutative unital ring, can we deduced that **MAXIMAL
QUOTIENT RING**=$R_S$, where $S$ is the set of all non
zero-divisors?

Is there any simple comprehensive references for maximal quotient
rings?

Comment: The name "quotient ring" is taken by something else, how about you call this, say an "idealizer", as analogous to normalizer.

Comment: May I ask what is the motivation behimd your questions?